# ExtJS: Getting response of Proxy post in local variable

Tags: json, extjs

I am new to ExtJS so please excuse if this is very basic. I googled but couldn't find any useful answer.

I have a Store with proxy type AJAX:

```
tableStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
               model: 'TableData',
               pageSize: 20,
               proxy: {
                   type: 'ajax',
                   url: url
               }
});
```

The call to `url` returns a JSON object. I want to get this JSON object in some local variable to do some processing.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the data obtained in the method transform:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'int'}
    , {name: 'title', type: 'string'}
]
, proxy: {
    type: 'rest'
    , reader: {
        type: 'json'
       , transform: {
            fn: function (data) {
                //you code here
                return data;
            }
            , scope: this
        }
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
   tableStore.getProxy().getReader().rawData
```

Comment: I have no idea if this is the only way to do this, but WOW!  Fantastic way to break the Law of Demeter!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: This is the way which i know

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I still get 'undefined' when I print this statement.